# YouTube IFrame API - setPlaybackQuality() is not changing video resolution from current playback time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have been trying to **change the video playback quality/resolution** of an iframe embedded video from YouTube using **YouTube IFrame API** by simply calling `player.setPlaybackQuality("hd720")` in the middle of playback.

According to YouTube: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setPlaybackQuality

> "The function causes the video to reload at its current position in the new quality."

***BUT, the quality of the video is changing only when the current playback time reaches the end point of the buffered old quality stream*. So, how can I force the player to *buffer the video at the new resolution at that very moment and start showing it from exactly that 'current duration' of the video just as it happens inside YouTube?***

By the way, I'm using pre-defined `iframe` tag in the html with all the parameters in the embed URL, like so:

```
<iframe id="genesis" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EZgTo1kKSsg?enablejsapi=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&rel=0&fs=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

And creating the player, like so:

```
$.getScript("https://www.youtube.com/player_api");

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('genesis', {
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        'onPlaybackQualityChange': onQualityChange
    }
});
}

function onQualityChange(){
    console.log('Now playing at ' + player.getPlaybackQuality());
    // Though it returns "hd720" within a few moments after hitting
    // setPlaybackQuality("hd720"), actual playback quality remains the older one.
}

$(document).on('click', '.play', function(){
    player.playVideo();
});

$(document).on('click', '#res_change_while_playing', function(){
    player.setPlaybackQuality($(this).data("id")); // data-id="hd720"
});
```

Please help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use seek function to re-buffer the video after you call setPlaybackQuality function

```
function onQualityChange(){
    player.setPlaybackQuality("small")
    player.seekTo(60) // or set to CurrentTime using player.getCurrentTime()
}
```

if this code doesnt work, you must stop the video first, then set the video quality, then seek to your time